# Problem when carrying out the route between two points

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet

You will see, I am trying to carry out a test with routing between two points, but the route does not come out despite the fact that I have directly copied the code from a tutorial. What can be causing this?

```
  let map = L.map('map').setView([57.74, 11.94], 30)
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
          L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
          L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
      ],
      routeWhileDragging: true
  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: have you added the routing library to your code?

Comment: Are there any errors visible in the dev console?